# SwiftUI - PreviewProvider with private var

Tags: swiftui, preview

I'm using `CoreData` to populate fields in a view that will get converted to a PDF. It would be great to have the preview feature working to help design the view, however, I've run into a snag with a private variable. Specifically, I'm getting an error that says, `"initializer is inaccessible due to 'private' protection level"`. As you can see below, `company` is the private variable. I can preview made up data for the `quote` variable using the code in the preview section, however, the same does not work for `company`.

```
struct PDFQuoteView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
    @State private var company: Company
    var quote: Quote?
    var body: some View { 

struct PDFQuoteView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
        let newQuote = Quote.init(context: context)
        let newCompany = Company.init(context: context)
        newQuote.quoteNumber = "AA0202"
        newCompany.name = "Acme Incorporated"
        return PDFQuoteView(company: newCompany, quote: newQuote).environment(\.managedObjectContext, context)
                .previewLayout(.fixed(width: 612, height: 792)) //this is the error line
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need `company` as State? Do you change this property in view, ie substitute with other company?

Comment: company uses the State wrapper because I call fetch from the view model in .onAppear. Without it I get the, "Cant assign to property, self is immutable" error.

Answer (score 2):

For the view as you have this error can be fixed by adding explicit `init`, like

```
struct PDFQuoteView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
    @State private var company: Company
    private var quote: Quote?

    init(company: Company, quote: Quote?) {
       self._company = State(initialValue: company)
       self.quote = quote
    }

    var body: some View { 
       ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't even need the init, you could just give your state a default value:
`@State private var company: Company = Company.company`
And you don't even have to declare the Type, it can be inferred:
`@State private var company = Company.company`

If you don't want to give your state and initial value it can be `nil` so long as your UI handles `nil`.
i.e. You should already be using a `default:` in switch statements.
But you could also just pass the state as a constant in the preview:
`PDFQuoteView(company: .constant(Company.company))`
I also noticed the posted sample is missing the closing bracket `}` for your Struct counting the body and PreviewProvider Struct. You may have not copied it, or there may be more to the end of your Struct, but make sure it's actually there if this was the entire Struct.