# Preview SwiftUI private non-default @State

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-previews

SwiftUI state properties [should be declared as private](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/state). This is good for encapsulating their values from containing views, but prevents a preview from setting a non-default state using the default initializer. For example, this doesn't compile:

```swift
struct TemperatureView: View {
    @State private var isHot = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(isHot ? "Hot" : "Cold")
    }
}

struct TemperatureView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Group {
            TemperatureView(isHot: true)
            TemperatureView(isHot: false)
        }
    }
}
```

Replacing `private` with `fileprivate` results in the same error. How can I preview private view state?

Comment: The question [SwiftUI - PreviewProvider with private var](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64383191/145173) is similar but involves additional aspects such as Core Data. This question focuses just on previewing view state.

Comment: The linked question is an exact duplicate since Core Data isn't relevant to the issue.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson The crux of what is being asked is indeed the same. Still, I thought asking this question might be the best way [to handle an unnecessarily complex question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/376416/167867). But I'm not sure and am looking forward to what guidance the community offers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

as it is `@State` you might want to do:

```
init() {}

fileprivate init(isHot: Bool) {
    self._isHot = State(initialValue: isHot)
}
```

Comment: Does `self._isHot = State(initialValue: isHot)` have a different effect than `self.isHot = isHot`?

Comment: if you want to initialize a @State var you have to do it like this, otherwise nothing happens.

Comment: Got it. Too bad setting up a preview requires so much verbosity. Hopefully, Apple improves this experience some day.

Comment: The necessary use of the underscore was not obvious to me, but was clarified here https://stackoverflow.com/a/68213830/41728